# finding the difference of sum in percentage after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'y': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'z':[100, 102, 110, 115, 200, 202, 230, 240]})

   x  y    z
0  a  0  100
1  a  1  102
2  a  0  110
3  a  1  115
4  b  0  200
5  b  1  202
6  b  0  230
7  b  1  240
```

After this:

```
df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].sum()

x  y
a  0    210
   1    217
b  0    430
   1    442
```

I want to find out the difference between sums in percentage for each group.
In other words I want this:

```
(217-210)/210 = 3.33
(442-430)/430 = 2.79
```

Comment: When you say `percentage`, do you mean with respect to the sum or the first element?

Comment: the difference between 210 and 217 is 3.33 percent. That is what I want

Comment: `(217-210)/210 = 3.33%` but `(217-210)/217 = 3.23%`

Comment: I want this (217-210)/210 = 3.33%

Comment: After sum there are always 2 values per group `x` ?

Comment: can you post your answer again please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) both `x` and `y` and take the `sum` as you already do, and then use [`DataFrame.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) to take the percentage change having grouped again by `x`:

```
g = df.groupby(['x','y'])['z'].sum()
g.groupby(level=0).pct_change().mul(100).dropna().reset_index(drop=True, level=1)

x
a    3.333333
b    2.790698
Name: z, dtype: float64
```

Comment: for me there is one extra value of b in the output..i.e b = 98.156682

Comment: what does `pd.__version__` give you?

Comment: it is this 0.23.0

Comment: Okay, I've just checked with the latest version and it's working for me... @amir